# Consistency of values of coefficients ($\alpha$) in Adaboost

Tags: probability, boosting

Based on the given set of data, Adaboost learns weights($\alpha$) corresponding to the weak classifiers. Now suppose that there is a huge chunk of data broken down into smaller parts, e.g: a total of $10^7$ data points (generated by the same unknown distribution) is divided into 10 parts each of sie $10^6$) by uniform random sampling without replacement. Now on each set of data Adaboost is made to learn the weights($\alpha$) keeping the bag of weak classifiers the same for all of them. Therefore, there will be 10 sets of values of $\alpha$ (considering the weights($\alpha$) hypotheses which are not chosen as 0).

Now all the 10 smaller chunks of data are generated from the same distribution. Then is it likely that learned 10 sets of $\alpha$ values  won't differ too much from each other (in probabilistic sense)? How to show that?

Comment: I would begin with simulating some data and running some experiments.  Have you tried this?